# Porting a Xamarin app to Maui. Getting infrequent startup crashes. (no more than 1 in 5 times)

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

Appears to be on the GC thread. (monosgen)

mono sgen is calling `CryptoNative_HmacUpdate`, which then runs some java, before calling `HMAC_Update` in `libcrypto.so` (which is a native android lib that exists on my moto test device).

I don't understand why GC is calling `CryptoNative_HmacUpdate` but purhaps it's in a Finalizer somewhere?

I'm not aware my app is making any explicit SSL/TLS socket calls at start up. Although we do open a WebView / Android System Webview, so it could well be that.

Has anyone else seen crashes like this, especial with maui apps that use Webview's?

The crash happens after the `Navigated` event from the `webView`.

Crash still occurs when webview just navigates to `<html><body>hello world</body></html>`.

Crash does **not** occur when I don't add the `webview`.

```
    --------- beginning of crash
10-13 12:00:55.355 13826 13923 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20 in tid 13923 (.NET TP Worker), pid 13826 (?????)
10-13 12:00:55.497 13826 13826 I ????: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 1120(70KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3874KB/7749KB, paused 118us total 93.853ms
10-13 12:00:55.503 13945 13945 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
10-13 12:00:55.505  1041  1041 I tombstoned: received crash request for pid 13923
10-13 12:00:55.511 13945 13945 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 13826 (target tid = 13923)
10-13 12:00:55.523 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-13 12:00:55.523 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'motorola/rav_retus/rav:11/RPJS31.Q1-53-12-17/62036b:user/release-keys'
10-13 12:00:55.523 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : Revision: 'pvt1'
10-13 12:00:55.523 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-10-13 12:00:55-0600
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : pid: 13826, tid: 13923, name: .NET TP Worker  >>> org.????? <<<
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : uid: 10610
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  0000006dd211b434  x2  000000000000000d  x3  0000006e6646f65c
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000006dd211b338  x5  0000006dd211b441  x6  482073616d6f6854  x7  656c646e69482073
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x8  0000006e51d128b4  x9  000000000000000d  x10 0000000000430000  x11 000000000000001e
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000006dd211b890  x14 0000000000000002  x15 00000000ebad6a89
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000006e51abb998  x17 0000006e51cfee74  x18 0000006dd1ddc000  x19 b400006f26a958d0
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000000000000d  x21 0000000000000000  x22 b400006ed6afc770  x23 0000006dd211b8a4
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000006dd211b434  x25 0000006dd211e000  x26 0000000000000042  x27 0000000000000004
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000006dd211b8b0  x29 0000006dd211b3c0
10-13 12:00:55.524 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :     lr  0000006e51cfee88  sp  0000006dd211b3c0  pc  0000006e51d0ccac  pst 0000000060000000
10-13 12:00:55.547 13826 13826 I Choreographer: Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-13 12:00:55.556  1167  1167 I QTI PowerHAL: Power setMode: 5 to: 0
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000109cac  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libcrypto.so!libcrypto.so (offset 0xce000) (SHA256_Update+24) (BuildId: cd2ee7e33e7cd10990aac7097cc2fdc2)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000fbe84  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libcrypto.so!libcrypto.so (offset 0xce000) (HMAC_Update+16) (BuildId: cd2ee7e33e7cd10990aac7097cc2fdc2)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 000000000001c31c  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (NativeCrypto_HMAC_Update(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jbyteArray*, int, int)+572) (BuildId: fc252985d5835aa1187d09ba9005ffc0)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000319148  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 000000000030f474  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.793 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 0000000000680e44  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000002ca38  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMac$Hmac.engineUpdate+4)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 000000000067e18c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 000000000023ca4e  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (javax.crypto.Mac.update+26)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 0000000000306a70  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13423079315433257381)+268) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #15 pc 000000000066cbf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #16 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #17 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #18 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #19 pc 0000000000556948  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+468) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #20 pc 0000000000556ae8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #21 pc 0000000000414b6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+660) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #22 pc 000000000037a2a0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+2512) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #23 pc 00000000003682e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+152) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #24 pc 0000000000012064  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.???-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Android.so (CryptoNative_HmacUpdate+148) (BuildId: 56fb3e4cee9166a04c35402acc08a0af9513ad79)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #25 pc 00000000001a9388  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.??????-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #26 pc 00000000001a7da8  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.?????-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #27 pc 000000000019d320  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.?????-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #28 pc 000000000019b074  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.????-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #29 pc 00000000000c5ed8  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.???-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #30 pc 000000000025e4b4  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.???-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke_checked+140) (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #31 pc 0000000000277440  /data/app/~~fwGew_P6fq7SfiMHLVwusg==/org.???-Vkz1EzfX8rJ5XFOctEN-tQ==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 52812271e2ea141c4ee822ccadaad7c1d4fe3bb5)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #32 pc 00000000000afce8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 1197163beea3f0b6686df3cb9bcee87c)
10-13 12:00:55.794 13945 13945 F DEBUG   :       #33 pc 00000000000502c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1197163beea3f0b6686df3cb9bcee87c)
```

**UPDATE**:

I had a bunch of background initialization that was being started via a Task.Run in the (MainPage) WebView::HandlerChanged event handler.

Moving this background initialization into MainActivity::OnCreate (Still using Task.Run), and I can no longer reproduce the crash (30+ full restarts and counting. Release as well as Debug builds).

My current **guess** is that there is some networking related setting change that is being made with this background initialization that is causing a conflict.

**UPDATE**:

Back again:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-05 10:31:31.079  Motorola moto g fast    Error   18659   DEBUG   backtrace:
      #00 pc 00000000000a3638  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libcrypto.so (SHA256_Update+24) (BuildId: 60cf60ff7e510cd1487a9f2035c95128)
      #01 pc 0000000000096e94  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libcrypto.so (HMAC_Final+140) (BuildId: 60cf60ff7e510cd1487a9f2035c95128)
      #02 pc 000000000001ded4  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (NativeCrypto_HMAC_Final(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*)+104) (BuildId: 40feb0ba06373f71e9c827cae9819953)
      #03 pc 000000000013ced4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #04 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #05 pc 00000000001a8a94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #06 pc 0000000000319148  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #07 pc 000000000030f474  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #08 pc 0000000000680e44  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+548) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #09 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #10 pc 000000000002ce78  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMac$Hmac.doFinal+4)
      #11 pc 000000000067e18c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #12 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #13 pc 000000000002cf2c  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/javalib/conscrypt.jar (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMac.engineDoFinal)
      #14 pc 000000000067e18c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #15 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #16 pc 000000000023c3c6  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar (javax.crypto.Mac.doFinal+18)
      #17 pc 0000000000306a70  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.13423079315433257381)+268) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #18 pc 000000000066cbf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+780) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #19 pc 000000000013cff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #20 pc 0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #21 pc 00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #22 pc 0000000000556948  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, std::__va_list)+468) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #23 pc 0000000000556ae8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithVarArgs<_jmethodID*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+92) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #24 pc 0000000000408620  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<true>::CallObjectMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+656) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #25 pc 0000000000379ec0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+1520) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #26 pc 0000000000367638  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+152) (BuildId: 0a722124e1d08ab1896df95b634bc489)
      #27 pc 0000000000012110  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Android.so (CryptoNative_HmacFinal+100) (BuildId: f2ad2be69afc021121a2b468ca26975d675de2f8)
      #28 pc 00000000001a91d0  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #29 pc 00000000001a7bf0  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #30 pc 000000000019d168  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #31 pc 000000000019aebc  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #32 pc 00000000000c5ef8  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #33 pc 000000000025e33c  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (mono_runtime_invoke_checked+140) (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #34 pc 00000000002772c8  /data/app/~~4je-EEc6sMLZokUr8KbgKg==/org.???-FxYAeFYM4oeAublQXnDvxw==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (BuildId: 943992f94e0687d44fe2a2fc0648c7cc473eee93)
      #35 pc 00000000000afce8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64) (BuildId: 1197163beea3f0b6686df3cb9bcee87c)
      #36 pc 00000000000502c8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1197163beea3f0b6686df3cb9bcee87c)
```

**UPDATE:**

setting some mono debugging options `setprop debug.mono.log "gc,assembly"`

yielded some interesting warnings:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
01-09 10:49:20.429  Motorola moto g fast    Debug   15414   monodroid-assembly  Entry 'CryptoNative_HmacFinal' from library 'libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Android' already loaded by another thread
01-09 10:49:20.427  Motorola moto g fast    Debug   15414   monodroid-assembly  Entry 'CryptoNative_HmacUpdate' from library 'libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Android' already loaded by another thread
```

(Non crash startups don't appear to show these Debug messages)

Comment: Have you tried catching the exception and see if it has any better details?

Comment: It's a segfault. (so not a managed/C# exception), so I don't think a try/catch would do anything. (plus it appears to be happening on the GC thread, so I'm not sure where the try/catch would go)

Comment: I see, is that all you get from the Device Logs? If so the only option we might have is to raise this with the Maui team and hope they have some good ideas... Just a quick question though, you aren't making this navigation on a background thread by any chance are you?

Comment: Good thought but no I'm not. (and yes that's basically all the info I get from logcat. no preceding managed exceptions or anything like that)

Comment: Can you create a Git repo that reproduces this issue with steps on how to repro it, i might take a look in my free time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new instance of the `NetworkCredential` class at the same time as doing WebView initialization caused the segfault.

My current hypothesis is that the Android `SecureString` implementation (that the `NetworkCredential` class uses) is implemented via `CryptoNative` calls.

My Solution/Workaround for this issue was to ensure all NetworkCredential operations were done on the same thread as the WebView initialization, preventing any issues caused by lack of thread safety.